# What is an alternative to announcement list that we can use in modern SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, feature

I Need to get announcement list in modern SharePoint site. how will get it or what is the alternative way.

Comment: which site template are you using? communication site or team site?

Comment: communication site

Comment: There is no similar list template available in modern experience. classic announcements list template is supported in team site but not in communication sites.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use News web part or Events web part as alternative.

[Use the Events web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-events-web-part-5fe4da93-5fa9-4695-b1ee-b0ae4c981909)

[Use the News web part on a SharePoint page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-news-web-part-on-a-sharepoint-page-c2dcee50-f5d7-434b-8cb9-a7feefd9f165)

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: this is an alternative way to the issue, but am looking for something similar to the list.

Comment: Agree with Ganesh Sanap. There is no similar list template available in the modern experience.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.